# Помогите с выбором книги по компьютерным сетям

Tags: сеть, книги

Приветствую уважаемую публику. Передо мной стоит дилемма, могу сейчас купить только одну книгу в бумаге:
Либо «Компьютерные сети» Виктора и Натальи Олифер, либо «Компьютерные сети» Эндрю Таненбаума...
С чего посоветуете начать? Все обзоры которые я читал упоминают эти книги, во всех они идут в разной последовательности... помогите определиться с выбором.

Comment: Рекомендую вообще не покупать книги в бумаге. Электронные и дешевле и удобнее.

Comment: И стоит тот же электронный Танненбаум в 4 раза дешевле бумажных Олифер (на примере "Озон").

Comment: Ну что ж поделать, если старомоден я, люблю в бумаге. Да и не я покупать буду, будут дарить. Лучше я попрошу что нибудь стоящее, а то опять фигню подарят :)

Comment: Почитайте отзывы на Озон. Там их десятки. Все точнее будет, чем пара коротких фраз здесь. По формальным признакам я бы советовал, если для обучения, то брать Олифер - они рекомендованы Министерством образования, да и поновее на четыре года будут (2020), чем Танненбаум (2016). А так мировое имя, конечно, у Танненбаума поизвестнее.